# Regex to redirect two different URLs starting with the same string

Tags: regex, nginx, redirect

Those are my two nginx rules :

```
rewrite ^(/v1/foobar)(.*)$ /final$2 permanent;
rewrite ^(/v1/foobar-tow)(.*)$ /final$2 permanent;
```

I expect that `/v1/foobar-two/foo` will use the second rule and then will redirect to `/final/foo` but I doesn't : since the URL starts with `foobar`, the first rule will be used and finally will redirect to `final-two/foo` : the concatenation of the first target and the difference between the first and second rule !

To solve the problem I've *just* inversed the rules, but I wonder if there is a better solution !

To sum up, this is what I'm looking for :

- /v1/foobar -> /final
- /v1/foobar/hello -> /final/hello
- /v1/foobar-tow -> /final
- /v1/foobar-tow/hola -> /final/hola

Comment: `rewrite` rules are processing from first till last by nginx, just swap them and everything should be ok.

Comment: The first rewrite is loose enough to capture the second one so it probably never evaluates the second condition.

Comment: You probably need `^(/v1/foobar)(/.*)?$` as the first rule. The slash will require the whole subpart to match the `foobar` part.

Comment: You could merge it into one rule by using `^(/v1/foobar(?:-tow)?)(.*)$`

Comment: @MonkeyZeus Indeed the best answer yet! However that could be simplified to `rewrite ^/v1/foobar(?:-tow)?(.*) /final$1 permanent;` (there is no need for two capture groups).

Comment: @IvanShatsky Yes, that would work too (more efficiently as well). I didn't want to change too many things at once for OP ;-)

Answer (score 0):

To avoid surprises with NGINX, and [increase configuration scalability](https://www.getpagespeed.com/server-setup/nginx-locations-performance-impact-and-optimizations), you should, generally:

- *try* to live without `rewrite` directive; as per NGINX author it simply appeared before `location` and in many cases you can now use `location` with capture groups in lieu of `rewrite`
- design your regular expressions in the way that the order of matching is not important, if possible
- use exact matching, where applicable
- isolate regular expression locations under a prefixed one

Putting all things together:

```
location /v1/ {
    location = /v1/foobar {
        return 301 /final;
    } 

    location ~ ^/v1/foobar/(\w+)$ {
        return 301 /final/$1;
    }

    location = /v1/foobar-tow  {
        return 301 /final;
    }

    location ~ ^/v1/foobar-tow/(\w+)$ {
        return 301 /final/$1;
    }
}
```

Comment: I doubt if this one would catch exactly `/v1/foobar/` and `/v1/foobar-tow/` URIs. Ok, we can add two more exact matching locations or modify the regex, but are you sure 
the game is worth the candle? Do not matching only one regular expresson for every request but have two regex matching locations instead? BTW, don't you know, is the PCRE JIT usage is still disabled by default in most nginx builds?

Comment: It does look like it's lengthy, but in the end (IMHO) appears more readable than `rewrite` after some time :) PCRE JIT *support* is automatically there in most recent builds but you still have to explicitly enable it in config with `pcre_jit on;`